# Is my code FLOSS just because it is published it on GitHub?

Tags: licensing, publishing, github

Does publishing my code on GitHub make it FLOSS automatically? Is there some license automatically assigned to it? Is it ["technically or say literally, open source"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/what-are-the-important-things-to-note-while-building-your-own-open-source-projec)?

Comment: Related question: [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1720/138)

Answer (score 24):

No, GitHub allows releases with different licenses. If you do not choose one, it is the usual basic assumption: all rights reserved. This is however overlayed by the terms of service you (implicitly or explicitly) accepted by using the site and creating an account. In the [case of Github](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/) it allows others to view and fork your project:

> However, by setting your pages to be viewed publicly, you agree to
>   allow others to view your Content. By setting your repositories to be
>   viewed publicly, you agree to allow others to view and fork your
>   repositories.

Other websites may have other terms of services, and in a few cases an open license is automatically assigned, for example in Wikipedia and StackExchange user posts have automatically the CC-BY-SA license assigned.

GitHub has a [help-site for choosing an open source license](https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/). Read there for more information.

At this help-site from Github is also [noted,](https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/#what-happens-if-i-dont-choose-a-license) that your project doesn't have an automatic license applied but some things from the terms of service:

> You're under no obligation to choose a license. It's your right not to
>   include one with your code or project, but please be aware of the
>   implications. Generally speaking, the absence of a license means that
>   the default copyright laws apply. This means that you retain all
>   rights to your source code and that nobody else may reproduce,
>   distribute, or create derivative works from your work. This might not
>   be what you intend.
>
> Even if this is what you intend, if you publish your source code in a
>   public repository on GitHub, you have accepted the Terms of Service
>   which do allow other GitHub users some rights. Specifically, you allow
>   others to view and fork your repository.
>
> If you want to share your work with others, we strongly encourage you
>   to include an open source license.

Comment: This post prompted me to post [a new question](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/how-does-githubs-forking-right-cope-with-an-all-rights-reserved-project).

Comment: I saw. And answered.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, [many open source projects does not specify the license](https://github.com/blog/1964-license-usage-on-github-com) on github. Legally, anything that comes without a license that provides freedoms to the users defaults to *all rights reserved*. On GitHub, there are *no defaults*.

Language giving permission to "view and fork" in the GitHub TOS are 1) not a license; and 2) may have no legal effect.  Do not confuse this with a real license.

Without a real FLOSS license associated with your project, it is not *free software*, and others will probably want to not use it because of the unknown legal hazards associated with doing so.

You decide what license to use. A rundown of the properties of each is outside the scope of this question. However, to be called "Open Source" or "Free Software", the license should preserve the [four essential freedoms](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

The FSF provides an [excellent guide](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html) to free software licenses.

There is also a [licensing FAQ at GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/).

Comment: I don't think it is technically open source without a license. It's still all rights reserved, so proprietary.

Comment: The quotes around "open source" means that it is *not* Open Source (as defined by OSI), The intent behind "technically" was to say that it technically open for anyone to *read* the source (they just can't do anything with it). And, yes: This reflects my animosity against the confusing term "Open Source".

Comment: Oh, I understand. But the animosity could also be put towards free software and free software (as defined by the FSF). All the terms can be misleading sadly.

Comment: @FreeRadical you could use the term "source available"

Comment: ***Many open source projects does not specify the license***. I don't believe that. Could you back up that claim?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Less that 20% of GitHub repositories is associated with a license. Source: https://github.com/blog/1964-license-usage-on-github-com

Comment: *Github* repositories, not all open source projects. I've edited your answer to make a note of that.

Comment: Zizouz212: nice answer, but with a mistake you should really clarify: you write "many open source projects does not specify the license on github", but what I think you mean is "many projects on github that the author would *like* to release as open source are not"