# How can I license my GitHub Page hosted in a open-source template?

Tags: copyright, github, cc-by-sa, website

Let's assume the following situation:

- I have created a personal blog hosted on Github Pages, based in a modified version of a template from [HTML5UP](https://html5up.net/), which is available for free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license.
- Inside this blog, I will generate original, digital, and creative content. In addition, I will use it as a personal portfolio for photography.
- I want to protect all my content (my digital creations and original photos) against any kind of use, personal or commercial (copyright license).
- Right now, the repository is public. But I would like to make it as private as possible, where only I can make any modifications.

My question is: Which are the steps I should take in order to license my hosted-Github Page and to protect my content, taking into account that I am using a template with Creative Commons Attribution 3.0? I do not want people to confuse the license from the template with the license from the content of the blog.

In my public repository, there is already a `LICENSE.txt` for the template. Can I just add another one for my content specifying the other type of license (copyright)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple: CC-BY 3.0 means you have to give attribution. It doesn't require you to share any code or whatsoever. Thus it is generally deemed appropriate to have e.g. in your page footers a line which reads like:

> This page uses the CC-BY 3.0 licensed template [HTML5UP](https://html5up.net/).

In your repository itself I'd be explicit in the LICENSE.txt

> All content copyright edualvarado, all rights reserved.
>
> The web page uses the [CC-BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) licensed template [HTML5UP](https://html5up.net/).

You might want to rename LICENSE.txt to something like LICENSE_pagetemplate.txt to make it clear that it applies to the web page template you use. And restrict LICENSE.txt to the above two lines or something similar.

Comment: Given that this is a GitHub Pages blog, how does an assertion of "all rights reserved" interact with GitHub TOS?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/how-does-githubs-forking-right-cope-with-an-all-rights-reserved-project