# Using a licensed code which use an unlicensed code without explicit mention an authorization from the author

Tags: licensing, github, unlicensed-code

I checked
[What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license?newreg=b5911384f42a4cb4bf98144d513446a6)
[Is my code FLOSS just because it is published it on GitHub?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/is-my-code-floss-just-because-it-is-published-it-on-github)
[Open source code with no license… can I fork it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148146/open-source-code-with-no-license-can-i-fork-it)
and other question on this website but haven't found what I am searching.

I want to use a [program](https://github.com/dmolina/cec2013single) on github licensed under GPL3.0. It's a python wrapper around a C software. The original C software is from an academic competition and neither the [archive released on github](https://github.com/P-N-Suganthan/CEC2013) or the [associated paper](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/EPNSugan/index_files/CEC2013/Definitions%20of%20%20CEC%2013%20benchmark%20suite%200117.pdf) mention a License.

The [website of the project](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/EPNSugan/index_files/CEC2013/CEC2013.htm) doesn't mention a License neither.

And the python wrapper has the following sentence in the README:

> This package is a unofficial package using cython for calling the official implementation in C source code.

enforcing the idea that no explicit authorization were given to the author of the wrapper, which was made later, compared to the R wrapper mentioned on the website.

From what I saw on others questions, if I want to use the original C code, I need the permission of the original author, who I can mail.
However, would this authorization extend to the use of the code inside the python wrapper? Can I use the python wrapper code without worrying about the lack of license in the original code (I mean legally, not ethically)?

Comment: Have you also read [Someone open-sourced an un-open-source project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10028/someone-open-sourced-an-un-open-source-project)?  It seems to me that that, combined with the questions you link above, pretty much answers your question.

Comment: "Would this authorization extend to the use of the code inside the python wrapper?" -- The wrapper is a separate piece of software and according to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dmolina/cec2013single) it seems to be licensed under the GPL v3 license (as you also mentioned in your question). That means that you already have permission to use the wrapper under the specified license. So at least for this part of your question, you've already answered it yourself.

Comment: @MadHatter I haven't read it, and it indeed helps a lot answering the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JackRed thanks for accepting the duplicate, and thus putting your question to bed.  Also, welcome to OS.SE.  I'm sorry your first post here got closed, but you did a pretty good job of research before posting, for which we thank you, and it's not your fault you didn't happen to find the one key question.  I hope you'll post more questions - and answers - in the future.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for the welcoming! I understand about the closed post, I'm glad I got my answer.